# How can I select an href element by Selenium webdriver in java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

On the page to be tested i have this code:

```html
<a href="#sideMenu1756" data-toggle="collapse" class="parent list-group-item list-group-item-success">
    Entrada de Operações <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
```

The script i ran was this:

WebElement entradaoperacoes3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='#sideMenu1756']"));

Comment: what error you are getting? Make sure the script wait for the element. Also try with `//a[normalize-space(.)='Entrada de Operações']` as `sideMenuxxxx` might be changing dynamically.

Comment: aria-hidden="true" means the element is not displayed (yet or no longer or not at all).

Comment: This is the error presented:" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Compound class names not permitted
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#invalid_selector_exception "

Answer (score 0):

try accessing the element with the partialLinkText or linkText methods from selenium. These are methods specific for  tag

entradaoperacoes3 = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Operações"));

Also, make sure you wait for the element to be visible before trying to access it.

Comment: unfortunately there are other elements identical to this <a> </a>, only with the different 'href' element. So 'partialLinkText' or 'linkText' does not work in this case.

Comment: ok, then you could try this:
entradaoperacoes3 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='sideMenu1756']"));

Comment: This didn't work either! Within [href * = 'This property can only be of type' text 'and not the actual link like' sideMenu1756 ']

Comment: what you could try then, is to not uniquely identify it the element, but rather identify all your elements and access it by index using the findElements something like 
 List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("list-group-item-success"));
elements.get(<index of your item>); Not the prettiest solution, but it might unblock you. Also you might want to ajust a bit the cssSelector as I do not see all the other elements, not sure that is ok. But this approach might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
WebElement entradaoperacoes3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'sideMenu1756')]"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work! The following error appears: "org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Compound class names not permitted For documentation on this error, please visit: selenium.dev/exceptions/#invalid_selector_exception "